# Initial Value of Locator in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, evaluation, locator

Consider the following example:

```
Manipulate[u, {u, Locator}]
```

which evaluates to:

[image]

Now, if you start moving the locator around, you will see the coordinates update:

[image]

So the question is, why is the initial value of the locator (`Automatic` in this case since none was specified) held unevaluated and what can be done for `Manipulate` to evaluate the initial value?

Comment: Any thoughts on why user interaction evaluates the initial value and whether this is intended behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Initialization`:

```
Manipulate[u, {u, Locator}, Initialization :> (u = {0, 0})]
```

[image]

Comment: Also `Manipulate[u, {{u, {0, 0}}, Locator}]`

Comment: This is interesting, it seems that this works for lists but if you use other kinds of heads, this stops working... Try replacing `{0,0}` in your answers with `Scaled[{1,0}]` for example and you see that this isn't evaluated.